# If GCC only finds a static library and not a dynamic one, does it resort to static linking the found file?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Please consider the following command:

```
gcc myfile.c -o myapp.exe -Lmydir -lmylib
```

`mydir` inclues the following file:

```
`libmylib.a`
```

I know that by default, `gcc` wants to do *dyanmic* linking. However, as you can see it does not find a `libmylib.so` dynamic library, only a `libmylib.a` *static* one.

Does that mean that `gcc` will *statically link* `libmylib.a` into the result executable?

Comment: I would say yes. If it find only one version of the library then it choose that one. So if it an .a then it will link statically. At least as far as I know. But you could check this easily I guess. Use `ldd` on the program or `readelf -d myapp.exe | grep 'NEEDED'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is up to the linker, not GCC. Standard linker behavior is to try a dynamic library then a static one *in each path component* of the link search path. For example, if the first directory searched has only a static library by the name, the second directory will not be searched at all, even if it has a dynamic one. As such, for normal user expectations to work correctly, corresponding dynamic and static versions of the same library need to be placed in the identical location.

Comment: I see. Is there such a thing is "dynamically linking a `.a` static library", or "statically linking a `.so` dynamic library"? Or is it always the case that the linking strategy has to match the file type?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. If the output is a dynamic executable and the current mode is `-Bdynamic`, dynamic libraries will be preferred if they exist. If the current link mode is `-Bstatic` or no dynamic library is found but a static one is, the static library will be static linked into the output executable. This is independent of whether the executable is dynamic or static. You can change between `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` on a per-library basis by inserting the option (using `-Wl`) between `-l` options.